# How to execute nant build file from another build file?

Tags: nant, nant-task

I have a big project here where I created some build files which I use in different scenarios including ccnet. So, I have BF1.build and BF2.build

I just want somewhere in BF1 to call/execute the script from BF2.build

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete that. Just found a solution:

```
<target name="somename" >

<nant>
    <buildfiles>
        <include name="BF2.build" />
    </buildfiles>
</nant>  </target>
```

[NAnt docs](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/tasks/nant.html)